# How do i put a bunch of variables into categories and then find out from which category a specific variable is?

Tags: ios, swift, string, variables

I'm trying to add jokes into different categories and then later find out from what category the joke was shown to change a variable indicating how many times a joke from that category was shown.

Your assistance in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a "Joke" class which holds both a string containing the joke and a jokeType property which could be an enumerated type containing the different joke categories, or else just a string describing the category. Then, just make an array of joke objects and any time you show one of the jokes just check its jokeType property.  Also obviously you'd need a counter variable for each category.